# Unhandled promise rejection with Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, headless-browser, nightmare

I'm receiving an "Unhandled promise rejection" when attempting to load a page (from codefights.com) and waiting until certain html elements have loaded.

Here is my code:

```
import * as Nightmare from 'nightmare';

const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

nightmare
    .goto('https://codefights.com/interview/EDaACHNYHyH6qQFAL')
    .wait('body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
    .evaluate((selector) => {
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }, 'body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
    .end()
    .then((functionTitle) => {
        console.log(functionTitle);
    });
```

Here is the exception:

`Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Evaluation timed out after 30000msec.  Are you calling done() or resolving your promises?`

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the timeout from occuring or the rejection from being unhandled?

Comment: @Bergi I'm trying to prevent the rejection from being unhandled. I think I figured it out too, the evaluate function must return a promise if it's followed by a `then`.

Comment: Then just chain a `.catch(handler)` to your chain or pass the handler as the second argument to the final `chain`.

Comment: I dug into the [documentation a bit more](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#interact-with-the-page) and it suggests that `evaluate` should return a `Promise`: "`Promise`s are also supported as a part of `evaluate`. If the return value of the function has a then member, `.evaluate()` assumes it is waiting for a promise."

Answer (score 1):

After digging through [the documentation a bit more](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#interact-with-the-page), I found out that `evaluate` should return a `Promise` if it's followed by `then`.

> `Promise`s are also supported as a part of `evaluate`. If the return
>   value of the function has a then member, `.evaluate()` assumes it is
>   waiting for a promise.

Here is how it looks when it's fixed:

```
nightmare
.goto(url)
.wait('body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
.evaluate((selector) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(document.querySelector(selector).innerText);
        } catch (exception) {
            reject(exception);
        }
    });
}, 'body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
.end()
.then((functionTitle) => {
    console.log(functionTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the rejection, just chain a `.catch(handler)` to your chain or pass the handler as the second argument to the final `chain`:

```
nightmare
.goto('https://codefights.com/interview/EDaACHNYHyH6qQFAL')
.wait('body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
.evaluate(selector => {
    return document.querySelector(selector);
}, 'body > div:nth-child(9) > div > div.page--header > div > span')
.end()
.then(functionTitle => {
    console.log(functionTitle);
}, error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```